# Problem with time series regression using dynlm and ts(), ("Error in zoo...")

Tags: r, time-series

My data is sctructured like the df given at the bottom. I would like to conduct a time series regression using the following code:

```
df_ts <- ts(df, start = 2001, end = 2021, frequency = 1)

dynlm(d(value1) ~ time + L(value1, 1) + L(value2, 1) +
        d(L(value1, 1)) + d(L(value1, 2)) + d(L(value1, 3)) + d(L(value1, 4)) +
        d(L(value2, 1)) + d(L(value2, 2)) + d(L(value2, 3)) + d(L(value2, 4)),
      data=df_ts)
```

But I get this error message:

```
Error in zoo(structure(x, dim = dim(x)), index(x), ...) : 
  “x” : attempt to define invalid zoo object
```

I don't understand why I get any error with respect to zoo at all, since I use ts() to convert my data to annual time series. I guess I have a general misunderstanding of the package and the functions I am using. I tried to find out using the documentation, google and SO, but I still couldn't manage to solve the problem. If I've made an obvious mistake, please cut me some slack as I'm quite the noob.

At some point I figured that the panel structure of my data might be the problem, so I split the data into several dfs, one for each industry. Running the code provided above on each df separately (after converting via ts() ) generated the same error, though.

My data looks like this:

```
year <- c(rep(2001:2021,3))
industry <- c(rep("a",21),rep("b",21),rep("c",21))
value1 <- c(sample(1:300, 63))
value2 <- c(sample(1:300, 63))
df <- data.frame(year, industry, value1, value2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference to zoo is because internally `dynlm` converts the input to a zoo object and works with that.  This is mentioned in `?dynlm` .

The formula refers to a `time` column but there is no such column in the data.  Presumably you want `time(df_ts)`.  Also some abbreviations are possible.  We use the input from the Note at the end where we have reduced the input to industry "a",  It can be repeated for the other industries by repeating the code or using lapply over the levels.

```
dynlm(d(value1) ~ time(ts.a) + L(value1) + L(value2) +
  d(L(value1, 1:4)) + d(L(value2, 1:4)), data = ts.a)
```

giving

```
Time series regression with "ts" data:
Start = 2006, End = 2021

Call:
dynlm(formula = d(value1) ~ time(ts.a) + L(value1) + L(value2) + 
    d(L(value1, 1:4)) + d(L(value2, 1:4)), data = ts.a)

Coefficients:
       (Intercept)          time(ts.a)           L(value1)           L(value2)  
         2.849e+04          -1.375e+01          -4.349e+00          -4.021e-01  
d(L(value1, 1:4))1  d(L(value1, 1:4))2  d(L(value1, 1:4))3  d(L(value1, 1:4))4  
         2.970e+00           2.026e+00           1.259e+00           8.141e-01  
d(L(value2, 1:4))1  d(L(value2, 1:4))2  d(L(value2, 1:4))3  d(L(value2, 1:4))4  
         7.153e-02          -6.618e-03           2.915e-04           1.351e-01
```

### Note

We used this reducing it to level "a" and add `set.seed` to make it reproducible.

```
library(zoo)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
    year = 2001:2021,
    industry = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 21),
    value1 = sample(300, 63),
    value2 = sample(300, 63)
)

ts.a <- df |>
  subset(industry == "a", select = c("year", "value1", "value2")) |>
  read.zoo() |>
  as.ts()
```